# Dealing with Underflow in Adaptive Arithmetic Coding

Tags: python, math, encoding, compression

I've been implementing the PPM compression algorithm in python and have had some difficulty dealing with underflow with the adaptive arithmetic coder (when maintaining integers L and H for a finite-precision implementation).

From research, the solution is to detect when L = 01xxxx and H = 10yyyy and then rescale to make L = 0xxxx0 and H = 1yyyy1. A counter cntr is maintained and incremented every time this occurs and if the MSBs of L and H are equal it is output (as is normal), followed by cntr 0s if the MSB was 1 or cntr 1s if the MSB was 0. Cntr is then reset to 0 and encoding continues. Here is my code for encoding and decoding.

```
precision = 32
a = 0
b = 2**precision - 1
cntr = 0

def arithmetic_coder(low_cum_freq, high_cum_freq):
    global a, b, cntr
    old_a = a
    ret = ""
    w = b - a + 1
    a = a + math.floor(w * low_cum_freq)
    b = old_a + math.floor(w * high_cum_freq) - 1
    a_bin = np.binary_repr(a).zfill(precision)
    b_bin = np.binary_repr(b).zfill(precision)
    if a_bin[0] == b_bin[0]:
        ret += a_bin[0]
        if cntr > 0:
            if a_bin[0] == "0":
                ret += '1' * cntr
            else:
                ret += '0' * cntr
            cntr = 0
        a_bin = a_bin[1:] + "0"
        b_bin = b_bin[1:] + "1"
    while a_bin[0] == b_bin[0]:
        ret += a_bin[0]
        a_bin = a_bin[1:] + "0"
        b_bin = b_bin[1:] + "1"
    while a_bin[0] == "0" and a_bin[1] == "1" and b_bin[0] == "1" and b_bin[1] == "0":
        a_bin = a_bin[0] + a_bin[2:] + "0"
        b_bin = b_bin[0] + b_bin[2:] + "1"
        cntr += 1
    a = int(a_bin, 2)
    b = int(b_bin, 2)
    return ret

    precision = 32
```

And the decoder:

```
a = 0
b = 2**precision - 1
decode_pos = 0

def arithmetic_decoder(frequencies):
    global a, b, decode_pos, cntr
    w = b - a + 1
    old_a = a
    frequencies = [0] + frequencies
    for i in range(1, len(frequencies)):
        frequencies[i] += frequencies[i - 1]
    index = math.floor(((int(enc[decode_pos : decode_pos + precision], 2) - a + 1) * frequencies[-1] - 1) / w)
    char = 0
    for i in range(len(frequencies)):
        if frequencies[i] > index:
            char = i - 1
            break
    a = old_a + math.floor(w*frequencies[char]/frequencies[-1])
    b = old_a + math.floor(w*frequencies[char + 1]/frequencies[-1]) - 1
    a_bin = np.binary_repr(a).zfill(precision)
    b_bin = np.binary_repr(b).zfill(precision)
    while a_bin[0] == b_bin[0]:
        a_bin = a_bin[1:] + "0"
        b_bin = b_bin[1:] + "1"
        decode_pos += 1
    a = int(a_bin, 2)
    b = int(b_bin, 2)
    return char
```

When I encode then decode a text file, the output of the decoder is correct up to a point (where the underflow corrector first activates) and from then on it is gibberish.

Is there something that needs to change with the decoder or am I simply not understanding underflow correction with arithmetic coding?

Thanks.